# Dagger2, interface in presenter

Tags: android, dagger

I am learning dager2. And as for me i have not clear moment with interface and presenter. For example i have a project without dagger2.

```
MainActivity <- acitivty
MainView <- interface
MainPresenter <- class
```

I have realized interface MainView in MainActivity

```
MainActivity implements MainView {

   onCreate(///) {
       MainPresener mP = new MainPresenter(this)
        mp.getData() 
   }        

   @overirde // method from interface
    public void test(String test) {///}
}
```

My presenter

```
MainPresenter{
public void MainPresenter(MainView mainView) {///}

public void getData() {mainView.test("test")}
}
```

My interface

```
inreface MainView  {
public void test(String test)
}
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------

So, as for me everething is clear. When i used dagger2 i had a code like this:

interface UserView

```
interface UserView {
    fun setData(data: String)
}
```

for a test i created two module

```
@Module
class HelpersModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideUserHelper(): UserHelper {
        return UserHelper()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideGeneralHelper(): GeneralHelpers {
        return GeneralHelpers()
    }

}
```

and

```
@Module
class UserModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideUserPresenter(userHelper: UserHelper,
                             generalHelpers: GeneralHelpers): UserPresenter {
        return UserPresenter(userHelper, generalHelpers)
    }
```

also i had AppComponent

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(UserModule::class, HelpersModule::class))
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {
    // inject to ...

    // activities
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

My presenter

```
class UserPresenter(private val userHelper: UserHelper, private val generalHelpers: GeneralHelpers) {

    private  val TAG: String = UserPresenter::class.java.simpleName

    fun getUser() {
        Log.e(TAG, "getUser")

    }

}
```

My activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), UserView {

    private var TAG: String = "MainActivity"

    @Inject
    lateinit var userPresenter: UserPresenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // init app component, this activity
        App.appComponent.inject(activity = this@MainActivity)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        userPresenter.getUser()
    }

    override fun setData(data: String) {
        Log.e(TAG, "data from presenter $data")
    }

}
```

**My question:** How i can call methods from interface UserView  in UserPresenter like this:

```
    class UserPresenter(private val userHelper: UserHelper, private val generalHelpers: GeneralHelpers) {

        private  val TAG: String = UserPresenter::class.java.simpleName

        fun getUser() {
            Log.e(TAG, "getUser")
// call method from interface UserView, and display data in MainActivity
            userView.setData("Alex, ${userHelper.getDefAge()} ${generalHelpers.generalHelper()}")
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to inject your view into the presenter either by using the DI framework or by manually setting the view.

**Option 1**

```
class UserPresenter(private val userHelper: UserHelper, private val generalHelpers: GeneralHelpers) {
   private val TAG: String = UserPresenter::class.java.simpleName
   lateinit var userView: UserView 

   fun getUser() {
      Log.e(TAG, "getUser")
      userView.setData("Alex, ${userHelper.getDefAge()} ${generalHelpers.generalHelper()}")
   }
}
```

Call onCreate() in your Activity

```
presenter.userView = this
```

---

**Option 2**

You will have to create another module preferably an interface or an abstract class to **include** in your *UserModule*. Dagger doesn't know how to provide the UserView, so we need to instruct the DI how-to.
Change to Presenter's constructor:

```
class UserPresenter(private val userHelper: UserHelper, private val generalHelpers: GeneralHelpers, private va userView: UserView ) {
   private val TAG: String = UserPresenter::class.java.simpleName

   fun getUser() {
      Log.e(TAG, "getUser")
      userView.setData("Alex, ${userHelper.getDefAge()} ${generalHelpers.generalHelper()}")
   }
}
```

```
@Module
abstract class UserViewModule {
   @Binds
   abstract fun bindUserView(activity: MainActivity): UserView
}

...
// in your UserModule
@Module(includes = [UserViewModule::class])
class UserModule { 
...
}
```

I think you might be able to simplify the above using one module if Dagger knows how to provide the rest of presenter's dependencies. Get rid of **UserModule** in favor of UserViewModule.